# Инерция блока при скролле страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css, анимация

Есть небольшой блок с position fixed, расположенные слева в центре экрана. Нужно, чтобы при скролле он как бы отставал, а после, когда перестали скроллить плавно возвращался на своё место. Пытался добавить ему нужный класс в зависимости от того, происходит скролл страницы вверх или вниз, и уже в css изменял этому блоку с нужным классом позиционирование. Но происходит это очень дёргано и не красиво. Хотелось бы, чтобы всё было плавно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать

Comment: Так? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086843/easing-effect-for-positionfixed-div

Comment: @UserTest013 да, так, но я не очень понимаю как этот код можно написать на чистом js

Comment: А ещё там в примере элемент уходит за край экрана, а мне нужно, чтобы он только немного поднимался или опускался в зависимости от направления скролла

Answer (score 1):

Решил задачу следующим кодом:

```js
 let lastScroll = 0;
window.addEventListener('scroll', pc_scroll);
function pc_scroll() {
    let st = pageYOffset;
    let mobLink = document.querySelector('.pc-links');
    if (st > lastScroll) {
        mobLink.style.setProperty('top', `calc(50% - ${(st-lastScroll)}px)`);
    } else {
        mobLink.style.setProperty('top', `calc(50% + ${-(st-lastScroll)}px)`);
    }
    lastScroll = st;
    if (st == lastScroll) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            mobLink.style.setProperty('top', '50%');
        }, 100);
    }
}
```